# What is an Uptight™ Word?

Tags: pattern, english, letters, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Uptight Word™.
Composed Words™ are not Uptight Words™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| UPTIGHT WORDS™ | COMPOSED WORDS™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABASHED | ANGRY |
| BRAZEN | CALM |
| CRAZY | COMPOSED |
| EXCITED | COOL |
| EASY | FURIOUS |
| FIERCE | HALCYON |
| HUSHED | MAD |
| MILD | NERVOUS |
| PLACID | RELAXED |
| ROUSED | RUFFLED |
| SEDATE | SERENE |
| TENSE | UNCOOL |
| UPTIGHT | VIOLENT |
| WORRIED | WILD |

Here they are in a CSV format:

```
UPTIGHT WORDS™,COMPOSED WORDS™
ABASHED,ANGRY
BRAZEN,CALM
CRAZY,COMPOSED
EXCITED,COOL
EASY,FURIOUS
FIERCE,HALCYON
HUSHED,MAD
MILD,NERVOUS
PLACID,RELAXED
ROUSED,RUFFLED
SEDATE,SERENE
TENSE,UNCOOL
UPTIGHT,VIOLENT
WORRIED,WILD
```

Comment: Is Composed the exact opposite of Uptight, or are the two properties unrelated except that Composed implies not Uptight?

Comment: @randal'thor I just updated the question, yes you could replace "composed" with "not uptight" the two sets are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Furious, angry, mad and violent are all composed...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil ... and hushed, placid, and sedate are all uptight.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Doesn't the new tag kinda spoils the puzzle ?

Comment: @Ankoganit, it has already been solved though

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That tag would be inappropriate for this question even if it wasn't a spoiler, since tags apply to questions and not their answers. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An Uptight Word™ is a word ...

> ... whose Scrabble score is a prime number.

Conversely, a Composed Word™ ...

> ... has a non-prime or composite Scrabble score: The score is *composed* of several factors.

Evidence section:

> `ABASHED: 13         ANGRY: 9`
>  `BRAZEN: 17          CALM: 8`
>  `CRAZY: 19           COMPOSED: 15`
>  `EXCITED: 17         COOL: 6`
>  `EASY: 7             FURIOUS: 10`
>  `FIERCE: 11          HALCYON: 15`
>  `HUSHED: 13          MAD: 6`
>  `MILD: 7             NERVOUS: 10`
>  `PLACID: 11          RELAXED: 15`
>  `ROUSED: 7           RUFFLED: 14`
>  `SEDATE: 7           SERENE: 6`
>  `TENSE: 5            UNCOOL: 8`
>  `UPTIGHT: 13         VIOLENT: 10`
>  `WORRIED: 11         WILD: 8`

Comment: How did you think of that ? Oo